# Disabled element through the JS code - not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have two radio buttons, click on one of them I will allow the input below and click on the other I allow the second input.

Here my HTML:

```
 <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                <input onclick="ChangeChoise(1);" type="radio" name="radio-choice" id="radio-choice-1" value="choice-1" checked="checked" />
                <input  id="Input1"/>
                <input onclick="ChangeChoise(2);" type="radio" name="radio-choice" id="radio-choice-2" value="choice-2" />
                <input disabled="disabled"  id="Input2"/>
</fieldset>
```

At first the second input is not enabled, by clicking on the input ran the following function:

```
var ChoseDiv = 1;
function ChangeChoise(NumChoise) {
    if (ChoseDiv == NumChoise)
        return;
    else
        if (NumChoise == 1) {
            $('#MyInput2').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            $('#MyInput1').attr('disabled', '');
        }
        else {
            $('#MyInput1').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            $('#MyInput2').attr('disabled', '');
        }
    ChoseDiv = NumChoise;
}
```

**It did not work**

I tried also this way: `$('#MyInput2').removeAttr('disabled');` And it did not work..

What am I missing??

Comment: You have different id's in inputs, 'Input1' in one case, 'MyInput1' in other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery Mobile has functions for enable/disable:

```
$('#Input1').textinput('disable');
$('#Input2').textinput('enable');
```

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/5N3vL/

And here's a official documentation: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/forms/search/methods.html

Comment: No problem m8, I am glad to help.